# copying a list without it being linked to its original several times! java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a problem duplicating ArrayLists to place them into a Hashmap. I have an ArrayList filled with potential resources. I need to add a time dimension to them which i implement through the use of a HashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Resource>> resourceTime = new HashMap<>();
```

Now i want each timestamp t to have exactly the same `ArrayList<Resource>`. This will later in the program be modified. The problem now is that if I fill the hashMap with the same original ArrayList it stays linked to this list. If I modify the HashMap for timestamp t it will be modified for every timestamp t.

code:

```
ArrayList<Resource> resourceUsageList = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Resource>> resourceUsage = new HashMap<>();

//The resourcearraylist gets filled with items or resources.

resourceUsageList.add(usage);

 for(int t = 0; t < TIME; t++){

   resourceUsage.put(t, resourceUsageList);
}
```

Is there any way i can fill every timestamp t with the same ArrayList without them being linked?

Comment: Just make copies of your list?

Comment: Don't put the same instance in that map. `resourceUsage.put(t, new ArrayList<Resource>());` If you need those to have the same "default content". Create one, then duplicate/clone the instance. But don't use the same instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create copies of the list and put the copies into the map. This can be done with the [ArrayList copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)), e.g.:

```
resourceUsage.put(t, new ArrayList<>(resourceUsageList));
```

Note however that the *list items* are still "shared" between the lists, i.e. if the `Resource` instances contained in the lists are modified, then multiple lists may be affected. 
This is not a problem if the `Resource`s are immutable or effectively never modified. Otherwise, you need to clone the resources as well.

Comment: The resource instances need to be modified. I created a new line replacing the old line: resourceUsageList.add(usage); with resourceUsageList.add(new Resource(usage)); I created a new constructor copying the elements of the original resource. Yet when I modify one, they still all change with it

Answer (score 0):

initialize an ArrayList and clone it for every timestamp. You can use ObjectUtils from org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.

```
for(int t = 0; t < TIME; t++){
    resourceUsage.put(t, (ArrayList)ObjectUtils.clone(resourceUsageList)); 
}
```

Comment: Adding the common apache just to clone a list ... there is a constructor for that, see [Alex Shesterov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49668756/4391450) solution.